# Timer.schedule(task, 0, 100) never fires

Tags: libgdx, timer

I added some code using `java.util.Timer` to execute my `spawnMonster` function every 100ms. It worked, until I tried instantiating images in it -- since it doesn't run on the libGDX core thread, there's no OpenGL context, so it can't do stuff with images.

I figured using the libGDX `Timer` class, which the javadocs say `runs on the core thread`, would solve this problem; but unfortunately, the timer code just doesn't execute.

I tried:

`- new Timer().scheduleTask(task, 0, 100)
- new Timer().scheduleTask(task, 0, 100, 99999)
- Timer.schedule(task, 0, 100)
- Timer.schedule(task, 0, 999999)
- Timer.start()
- t = new Timer(); t.scheduleTask(...); t.start();`

`task` appears to execute once, and only once; it never executes again. (It prints a date-time diff from a target time, so I can tell it's not running.)

Comment: Based on [this libGDX test](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/TimerTest.java), `new Timer(task, 1, 1)` seems to work, but I wonder about the performance of this.

Comment: Test #2: `new Timer(task, 0, 1)` also works, with the same caveats.

Answer (score 2):

The `scheduleTask` function's [source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/1077b2a9fc3e9fee9fc9982500c2d7f14542c771/backends/gdx-backends-gwt/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/gwt/emu/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Timer.java) suggests that it expects the input in terms of **seconds** instead of milliseconds.

```
public void scheduleTask (Task task, float delaySeconds, float intervalSeconds, int repeatCount) {
    if (task.repeatCount != CANCELLED) throw new IllegalArgumentException("The same task may not be scheduled twice.");
    task.executeTimeMillis = TimeUtils.nanoTime() / 1000000 + (long)(delaySeconds * 1000);
    task.intervalMillis = (long)(intervalSeconds * 1000);
    task.repeatCount = repeatCount;
    synchronized (tasks) {
        tasks.add(task);
    }
    wake();
}
```

The function converts `intervalSeconds` to milliseconds and sets the task's interval time to this value.

Therefore to have it execute every 100 ms, you should input `0.1` instead of `100`.